# Encountering Issue with setJavaScriptMode.unrestricted in Flutter Webview

Tags: flutter, user-interface, webview

I was following the tutorial below to create a webview.

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wPf-7rrng-8
```

But met with an unexpected error not shown in the video even though i try to follow through.

```
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class WebView extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebView({super.key});

  @override
  State<WebView> createState() => _WebViewState();
}

class _WebViewState extends State<WebView> {

  final controller = WebViewController();
  ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted) 
  ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('www.youtube.com'));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: WebViewWidget(controller: controller),
    )
    
    ;
  }
}
```

Here's the error i'm getting

[image: Text]

I've updated the minSdkVersion to 20.

Other than that, i really am clueless about what else to try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i removed the ; at the end of   final controller = WebViewController(); and the error is gone.